# Solve the equation $(2x^2-3x+1)(2x^2+5x+1)=9x^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the equation $$(2x^2-3x+1)(2x^2+5x+1)=9x^2$$

The given equation is equivalent to $$4x^4+4x^3-11x^2+2x+1=9x^2\\4x^4+4x^3-20x^2+2x+1=0$$ which, unfortunately, has no rational roots. What else can I try?

Comment: From the original equation, note that the left-hand side may be written as
$$(2x^2+x+1-4x)(2x^2+x+1+4x) = (2x^2+x+1)^2-16x^2$$

Comment: There are 4 numbers $\dfrac{2\pm\sqrt2}{2}$ and $\dfrac{-3\pm\sqrt7}{2}$ given in the question. Are these roots? If yes, these are all the roots because the degree is $4$.

Comment: @markvs It's a pretty safe assumption this is a homework question (or something of the sort) and the answers were given.  (or perhaps it's a case of "I used a CAS to find the roots, but I don't know how to find them by hand")

Comment: Then the Q should be closed because no context is given.

Comment: @markvs, yes, I posted the question already knowing the solution itself and the roots, just for the sake of it, to lose my time and the time of other people who are willing to help. So reasonable! Brava!

Comment: @BrianMoehring, I posted the answers because I thought they would be helpful if one solved the problem and wanted to see it they made a technical mistake. I didn't think it would be such a problem.

Comment: @Medi: There is no problem. I just voted to close your question for lack of context. But  4 more people are needed to actually close it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have, $$((2x^2+x+1)-4x)((2x^2+x+1)+4x)=9x^2$$
$$(2x^2+x+1)^2-16x^2=9x^2\;\Rightarrow\; (2x^2+x+1)^2=(5x)^2$$

Hence,  $\;2x^2+x+1=\pm5x$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Note that this method was posted $8$ minutes prior in a comment on the question (and it occurs also in many prior answers, i.e. the Q is a dupe).

Comment: @BillDubuque After I submitted the answer I noticed that Brian mentioned it in the comments. I wanted to delete my answer but I had already two upvotes so I decided to keep it.

Comment: @BillDubuque, the question is what?

Comment: @Medi dupe means duplicate, i.e. this well-known method si already presented in many prior answers.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that your last equation can be written as the product of two polynomials of degree two, $$(2x^2-4x+1)(2x^2+6x+1)=0$$ It is then easy to find the roots of both polynomials.

Comment: Care to show how you factor it?

Comment: Classic Ruffini style: pick something to start with and pray for the best. In this case, starting with $2x^2$ made sense to me because of the kind of equation.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

As $x\ne0$ we can divide both sides by $x^2$ to find

$$(a-3)(a+5)=9\iff a^2+2a-24=0$$ where $2x+\dfrac1x=a$

Can you take it home from here?